# Window phone how to save xml data in my app to database on server?

Tags: xml, json, sqlite, windows-phone-7, windows-mobile

Window phone how to save xml data in may app to database on server ?

I am saving the data on my phone in xml and when there is network i need to send the data to the server and save into database .

How to transfer my data in xml to server ? How to add to database ?

Windows phone 7.1 mango os

Answer (score 0):

Windows phone can not make such network connections, if you want to write to database directly from your mobile device. You should use web service (like WCF) to transfer your XML to server and then save it into database.

Comment: How can i implement this ? Do you have any link for sample code ? I need both way communication i want data from server as well .

Comment: You can use this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_windowsphone7andthecloud_topic2 as an example.

Comment: I am using this code for (Windows phone and server communiction using WCF )[http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/how-to-consume-wcf-rest-service-returning-json-in-windows-ph/] for sending my data from phone to server and get response. But i am getting error "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."

Comment: Does your service work for non Windows Phone applications? Could you receive data from server? May be some test string.

Comment: Yes i tested the service it is working properly . I have tested it in wcf test client